# jxbrowser hang in CountDownLatch

Tags: eclipse, javafx, swt, jxbrowser

I am integrating jxbrowser into Eclipse using JavaFX to bridge between SWT and jxbrowser. It hangs very often, it looks like the browser got stuck in the countDownLatch waiting for the Socket. Anyone have any idea what the issue is? Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the stack trace of two hangs:

### Hang #1

```
Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
LockSupport.parkNanos(Object, long) line: not available 
CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).doAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) line: not available 
CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).tryAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) line: not available    
CountDownLatch.await(long, TimeUnit) line: not available    
LatchUtil.await(CountDownLatch, RuntimeException, int) line: 25 
LatchUtil.await(CountDownLatch, RuntimeException) line: 20  
SocketChannel.post(T) line: 189 
Browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(long, String) line: 1643
```

### Hang #2

```
Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
LockSupport.parkNanos(Object, long) line: not available 
CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).doAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) line: not available 
CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).tryAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) line: not available    
CountDownLatch.await(long, TimeUnit) line: not available    
LatchUtil.await(CountDownLatch, RuntimeException, int) line: 25 
LatchUtil.await(CountDownLatch, RuntimeException) line: 20  
SocketChannel.post(T) line: 189 
Browser.b(M) line: 274  
Browser.canGoBack() line: 1818
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the call stack of the **Hang #1** I see that JxBrowser is waiting until JavaScript code finish execution and returns the result. That's because you call the Browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue() function. This function blocks current thread execution and waits until the given JavaScript code is executed.

The call stack in the **Hang #2** indicates that you call the Browser.canGoBack() function that sends request to Chromium engine to find out whether we can go back and wait for reply from Chromium.

In case of **Hang #1** the reason might be in JavaScript code you are trying to execute. If JavaScript code contains endless loops, it might take a while to complete the execution. So, please check the JavaScript code you execute.

In case of **Hang #2**, if you see that this function is stuck for a while, the reason might be in a deadlock or Chromium engine just stuck for some reason and doesn't reply (possible deadlock in Chromium code).

Comment: I am aware of the executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue is synchronized. The  executeJavaScript method is async, but there is no callback function to get the result of the evaluation.

Comment: To get the result of the evaluation you should use the executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue() method.

Comment: Both cases work well for native browser, such as IE, safari, etc.. as well as the new JavaFX webview and older chromium (non jxbrowser).

Regarding **Hang #1**, I have a button in a html page that callback to a java function. The java function than immediately evaluate a javascript to have an alert dialog. Maybe this is the issue???

Comment: It's possible. In this case you might get a standard deadlock situation. It's hard to say whether it's true for your code, because I don't have access to your code or an example that reproduces this issue. You can take dump of threads when the issue happens and analyze it to find out whether it really has a deadlock or not.

Comment: I have identified the deadlock for the **Hang #1**, it is a deadlock in my javacode. I have resolved the issue.

Regarding **Hang #2**, is there a way for me provide additional information to see where it might be hanging in chromium?

Comment: It looks like calling any API to the browser from the main thread (JavaFX Application Thread) can trigger a hang. Do you have any suggesting how to make synchronized call into the browser from the main thread?

I am currently evaluating the jxbrowser, before my company can commit into purchasing license, I like to see a resolution for the hangs

Comment: I suppose you are getting this behavior on macOS platform. If so, then please make sure that you follow the instruction at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013071-using-jxbrowser-in-javafx and initialize BrowserCode in non-UI thread as shown in the example code.

Comment: This is on Windows 7, I didn't get a chance to test on Linux and Mac yet. But will will need to do so after I complete my evaluation on Windows first.

Comment: There's no special requirements to run JxBrowser in JavaFX on Windows. I suppose you have a simple deadlock in your environment. To find out what causes the deadlock and let you know how to fix it, I need to reproduce and investigate the issue in my environment.